# Bokeh Server doesn't show proper color for Multiple line plot

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I tried to plot multiple line on bokeh server and it almost work find.
But there is one problem of colors for lines.

My code is like below and when I operate in on bokeh server, it raise 'Runtime error' , why? how can i fix it?

```
p.multi_line('year', 'area',  alpha=0.6, color=BuGn8, source=source)

RuntimeError: 
Supplying a user-defined data source AND iterable values to glyph methods is
not possibe. Either:

Pass all data directly as literals:

    p.circe(x=a_list, y=an_array, ...)

Or, put all data in a ColumnDataSource and pass column names:

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=a_list, y=an_array))
    p.circe(x='x', y='x', source=source, ...)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bokeh.pallettes.BuGn8` is not a color, it's a list of colors. And, as the error states, you can't mix lists and a data source when using glyph methods.

If you need a different color for each line, you can add another column to your data source and pass the name of the column to the `color` attribute of `multi_line` glyph function.

A small example:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import BuGn8

p = figure()
ds = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(xs=[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],
                                ys=[[3, 2, 1], [4, 3, 2]],
                                color=[BuGn8[0], BuGn8[-1]]))
p.multi_line(xs='xs', ys='ys', color='color', source=ds, line_width=10)

output_file("test.html")
show(p)
```

Comment: Thank you. So I followed your comment and added color column to data source. Then, It worked!, But it show all lines in same color even though I put different CSS hex code

Comment: @toyaji Are you sure that the color is really the same, and not slightly different? Just in case, I have added an example.

Comment: Thank you, I found a solution from example!